# java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream()

Tags: jsp, servlets, illegalstateexception

Hi I am using servlet for printing purpose.

```
 response.setContentType("application/xls/csv/html/pdf/txt/html");
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+reportType+"."+reportView);
 response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
 response.getOutputStream().write(bytes,0,bytes.length);
```

Once everything(printing) is done I need to come back to the jsp (test.jsp) page where i called above servlet.

Getting error at the line :

```
request.getRequestDispatcher ("/jsp/test.jsp").include(request, response);
```

some more code.

```
        byte bytes[] = null;
    if(reportView.equalsIgnoreCase(VIEW_OPTION_HTML))
        bytes = GenerateHTML.generateHTML(jp);
    else if(reportView.equalsIgnoreCase(VIEW_OPTION_PDF))
        bytes = GeneratePDF.generatePDF(jp);
    else if(reportView.equalsIgnoreCase(VIEW_OPTION_XLS))
        bytes = GenerateXLS.generateXLS(jp);    
    else if(reportView.equalsIgnoreCase(VIEW_OPTION_OTD))
        bytes = GenerateODT.generateODT(jp);
```

Where reportView is view type and Jp is JasperPrint where I add printing data into it in other modules.

Comment: Content Type is : `application/xls/csv/html/pdf/txt/html` . Are you sure ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to "include" more content after sending the file? That will mess up the download. The content length header will also be incorrect.

Comment: Yes it is working code. Edit the question with more code